# How to set enabled/disabled dataset in a NVD3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I see in the legend on the top right here http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html radio buttons which I can click to turn on/off some datasets on the chart.

Is there an option to set this value for each dataset individually when I load data into chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a disabled flag on the data to hide it on load. If you go to [this example](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav) and add a disabled flag to the Data (JSON) tab you can see this.

```
function() {
  var sin = [],
      cos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
    cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
  }

  return [
    {
      values: sin,
      key: 'Sine Wave',
      color: '#ff7f0e',
      disabled: true
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: 'Cosine Wave',
      color: '#2ca02c'
    }
  ];
}
```